# view a particular line of a file denoted by a number

Tags: linux, bash, file, unix

Okay, this is probably an evident thing but it escapes me, as in it could probably be done in a much simpler way that I'm not aware of, so far.. 
Say there's a "file" and I want to view only what's on line number "X" of that file, what would be the solution?

here's what i can think of:

```
head -X < file | tail -1  
 sed -n Xp < file
```

is there anything else (or any other way) from the standard set of unix/gnu/linux text-tools/utils?

Comment: Essentially equivalent to the `sed` one: `echo Xp | ed -s file`

Answer (score 38):

`sed -n 'Xp' theFile`, where `X` is your line number and `theFile` is your file.

Comment: why was this downvoted? this is the most portable, simplest and most efficient way.  one doesn't even need the quotes.

Comment: @XXL - so? The point is that it's the best answer, so it should be voted as such.

Comment: @fig what are you talking about? how is it the best answer? the poster didn't bother reading the OP's post which **already** had this exact part. What's the use of posting the same thing?!

Comment: @XXL to reinforce that this *is* a simple and efficient way to do the task at hand

Comment: I rarely look for the answer in the question, so it's useful to have it as a separate answer, that can be voted up or down relative the other answers. +1

Answer (score 7):

in vi:

```
vi +X filename
```

in EMACS:

```
emacs +X filename
```

**in the shell:**

```
nl -ba -nln filename| grep '^X '
```

you can use context grep cgrep instead of `grep` to see some lines above and below the matching line..

---

**EXAMPLES:**

**print just that one line:**

```
$ nl -ba  -nln  active_record.rb  | grep '^111 '
111       module ConnectionAdapters
```

**with context:**

```
$ nl -ba  -nln  active_record.rb  | grep -C 2 '^111 '
109       end
110     
111       module ConnectionAdapters
112         extend ActiveSupport::Autoload
113
```

for context control in `grep` check `man grep` :

```
   Context Line Control
       -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
              Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

       -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
              Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.  Places a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

       -C NUM, -NUM, --context=NUM
              Print NUM lines of output context.  Places a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
```

Answer (score 4):

awk one-liner:

```
awk "NR==$X" file
```

bash loop:

```
for ((i=1; i<=X; i++)); do
  read l
done < file
echo "$l"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use vi

```
vi file
```

When in the file type

```
:X
```

where X is the line number you want to see

However, the sed -n Xp file is a good way if you really only want to see the one line

Comment: you can go directly to the line - as the other answer suggests