# CentOS - displaying 1 line of file only

Tags: linux, sed, centos

```
echo "Enter line number to display"
read number
sed -n $number /etc/passwd
```

I need to display only one line of text given by the user, in possible easy way. Above line is giving me error: 
sed -e expression char3,extra characters after command.

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [view a particular line of a file denoted by a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418908/view-a-particular-line-of-a-file-denoted-by-a-number), or [bash tool to get nth line from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct command is:

```
sed -n ${number}p /etc/passwd
```

(p is command to print)

Of course `sed` will do nothing useful after that, so it's even better to quit after having printed like Benjamin hinted to avoid reading the rest of the file:

```
sed -n ${number}'{p;q}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: This can be made faster with `{p;q}` instead of just `p` by preventing the rest of the file to be scanned.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I was thinking exactly that! I answered too fast and got an afterthought. Editing.